# J2ME build fails in codenameone build sever

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to build for symbian s60 in j2me and i am getting an error which i have no idea in how i can reszolve.here is the error.

> Warning: com.karimtstech.imasuccess.Exercises$3: can't find enclosing
>   method 'void
>   lambda$markExercise$35(java.util.Hashtable,com.codename1.ui.Container,com.codename1.components.InteractionDialog,com.codename1.ui.events.ActionEvent)'
>   in class com.karimtstech.imasuccess.Exercises Warning:
>   com.karimtstech.imasuccess.QuestionsAnswers$3: can't find enclosing
>   method 'void
>   showAnswerInHtml(java.util.Hashtable,com.codename1.components.MultiButton,com.codename1.ui.Form,java.lang.String)'
>   in class com.karimtstech.imasuccess.QuestionsAnswers Note:
>   com.codename1.impl.midp.GameCanvasImplementation: can't find
>   dynamically referenced class com.siemens.mp.game.Light Note:
>   com.codename1.impl.midp.GameCanvasImplementation: can't find
>   dynamically referenced class com.motorola.phonebook.PhoneBookRecord
>   Note: com.codename1.impl.midp.GameCanvasImplementation: can't find
>   dynamically referenced class com.nokia.mid.ui.FullCanvas Note:
>   com.codename1.impl.midp.GameCanvasImplementation: can't find
>   dynamically referenced class net.rim.device.api.system.Application
>   Note: com.codename1.impl.midp.GameCanvasImplementation: can't find
>   dynamically referenced class com.mot.iden.util.Base64 Note:
>   com.codename1.impl.midp.GameCanvasImplementation: can't find
>   dynamically referenced class mmpp.media.MediaPlayer Note: there were 6
>   unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces. You should
>   check if you need to specify additional program jars. Warning: there
>   were 2 unresolved references to program class members. Your input
>   classes appear to be inconsistent. You may need to recompile them and
>   try again. Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
>   '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'. Error: Please correct the
>   above warnings first.

Comment: Please accept correct answers by checking the green V next to the answer. Its otherwise hard for us to track what was answered and what wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

This is effectively this [known issues with Java 5 compatibility](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/codenameone-discussions/vQ1ImraGE2Q/2wgaOxWtzn8J) for old CLDC devices.

From the post:

> This can sometimes happen when inner classes reference generic parent
>   methods. Generally our Java 5 compatibility code converts
>   resp(java.util.Hashtable) to resp(codenameOneInternal.Hashtable) but
>   fails to do this for some unique cases of anonymous inner classes
>   bridge methods (special hidden methods generated to access the
>   argument).
>
> So if you have:

```
void resp(final Hashtable x) {
   new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             x.doSomething();
       }
   }
}
```

> Turn it to:

```
void resp(Hashtable x) {
   final Object temp = x;
   new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             Hashtable x = (Hashtable)temp;
             x.doSomething();
       }
   }
}
```

You can see a lot of other discussions covering this issue [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/codenameone-discussions/can$27t$20find$20enclosing$20method).